# Substitute wet milk for dry milk

Tags: baking, bread

I am needing to know how much normal milk do I use in place of 1/2 cup powdered milk in bread.

Comment: For what purpose?  There are some instances where it is not a direct substitute.

Comment: We really need the whole recipe to be able to determine whether substituting liquid milk in place of powdered milk is feasible or not. You'd likely need to reduce liquid elsewhere...

Comment: Makes sense. Better to reopen and properly close as a dupe.